# Sharp ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have some quantity varying with time (horizontal axis of the plot): it first oscillates then it has a jump (larger than the amplitude of the oscillations), then it continues oscillating. I have that quantity for a discrete set of cases (vertical axis of the plot).

I would like to find an option for `ListDensityPlot` that would allow me to really emphasize that jump: I don't want a nice smooth color scheme but rather one that would make the small oscillations invisible and would focus on the larger jump.

I can I control `ListDensityPlot` to do that ?

Comment: `(List)DensityPlot` is for a two-variable function such as $f(x,y)$, but from your description I understood that you have a single quantity varying in a single variable (time), i.e. $f(t)$.  Can you clarify? I thought you had something like `Plot[Table[Sin[x] + 3 UnitStep[x - 20] + i, {i, 0, 10, 2}] // 
  Evaluate, {x, 0, 40}]`.

Comment: It would be best if you could give an example, or maybe sample data (with as much information about the location of the jump as possible).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Sample data

```
pw = Piecewise[{{Sin[5 x + y], x < 5}, {3 + Sin[5 x + y], x > 5}}];

tab = Table[pw, {y, 0, 10, 0.1}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
```

#### Expansion function

```
expand[c_ /; c == 0] = # &;
expand[c_] := 1/2 - ArcTan[c - 2 c #] / ArcTan[c] / 2 &
```

`expand[x]` generates a function with expansion factor `x`.

```
Table[
  Plot[expand[c][x], {x, 0, 1}],
  {c, 0, 10, 2}
] ~Partition~ 3 // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### With expansion

We can use this on the data passed to the `ColorFunction` like this:

```
ListDensityPlot[tab, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"] @ expand[10][#] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Without expansion

The same plot without expansion:

```
ListDensityPlot[tab, ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

`InterpolationOrder`?

```
data = Table[
   With[{r = RandomReal[{0, 5}], 
     t = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]}, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t], 
     Sin[r^2]/r^2}], {10^4}];


ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh \[Rule] None, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus

```
ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]